# Android - Uninstalling using Code

Tags: android

How do I uninstall an application using code? I have no idea...

Comment: You mean to say that you want to develop an application that will function as an "uninstaller"? Revise your original question to reflect more facts and any code that you are stuck on instead of seeking help for an entire application.

Answer (score 1):

try use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DELETE) intent action to delete a package which name you set before by calling setData() on the intent.